# Top-Down Tab Key Section not working in Page Layout

Tags: lightning, page-layout, record-type, create-records

I'm also creating custom page layouts for this custom object, and want them to be able to tab down, rather than left to right. I believe I have the correct option chosen, but it does not tab correctly.

[image]

Is there another setting I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately top-down tab isn't supported in Lightning Experience. From Salesforce help:
[image]

[Here's a link to the original Salesforce help entry](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=layouts_in_lex.htm&type=5).